# About TTL configuration for States in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

lets assume that I have this configuration for a descriptor and actions were taken from here:

```
ValueStateDescriptor<Event> descriptor = ...;

StateTtlConfig ttlConfigOneHourAndReturnExpire = StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.hours(1))
            .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnReadAndWrite)
            .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.ReturnExpiredIfNotCleanedUp).build();

descriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfigOneHourAndReturnExpire);

/*after one hour when the state is expired*/
Event e = state.value(); (step 1 and 2)
e.count = e.count + 1; (step 3)
value.update(e); (step 4)
```

Will this means that after 1 hours when the state is already deprecated, things will happen in this order:

1. Return the previous state of the record in state besides is deprecated.
2. The previous state of the record will be cleaned up after that read.
3. Update the object after previous state was delivered and cleaned up (in read).
4. Update the state in this case will mean create the state again because the previous was already deleted and this value will take one more hour, or the state will be cleaned up at this point and not at point 1 and the object will not include the update and it will be stored in state as it arrived?

Hopping I could explain myself, because the documentation is not clear to me.

Starting from the point that I need to clean up the states when a day change happens and there is no way to do that using TTL, I want to clean the state after every hour but get the state before removed, update the current value and then create the state again for one more hour but having always the previous state before losing it.

Hope this makes senses and is possible to do in somehow.
Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to manipulate the state every hour, then create a custom `ProcessFunction` and use a timer to trigger that action.

Comment: By using a `ProcessFunction`, do I need to declare the window for 1 hour to use the `onTimer` method each hour and then clean the state without losing the actual state of it and re-update the value? if that is the case I cannot do it on that way, because the use case needs to trigger as fast as possible, not every hour. Am I right with the uses of `onTimer`?

Comment: It looks like using a `KeyedProcessFunction` is not needed to declare a `window` time

Comment: If I do something like this: ```long cleanupTime = getEndOfDay() - event.timestamp.getTime();
        ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(cleanupTime);``` when the method `getEndOfDay` give me last time of the day in long format, Am I be able to clean my keys at the end of the day? kind regards

Comment: I'm not understanding your requirements. You've said "I want to clean the state after every hour", but in the latest snippet of code it sounds like you just want to clean things up at the end of each day.

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion, I need to clean up all states at the end of the day and start a new day with no states at all. Am i doing it right with the snippet of above? Kind regards!

Comment: By doing this am I cleaning up the records state at the end of the day:`long cleanUpTime = getEndOfDay() - ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime();
        ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(cleanUpTime);` ? because it start cleaning states at the moment that I run the job. I change to `registerProcessingTimeTimer` because with `registerEventTimeTimer` seems not to work or not calling the `onTimer` method.

Comment: If you only need to remove state at the end of the day, then using TTL is fine. But it's still not clear to me what you mean by "clean up all states at the end of the day". Once you delete state, it's gone - so I don't know what you're trying to do by incrementing a counter in the state as part of the "cleanup", before you delete it.

Comment: The point is that I need to clean up all states (all keys) into one operator at the end of the day : 23:59:59, and if I use TTL for one day I think I will be not able of doing that because the size of the ckeckpoints are not reduced at the end of the day, and by using TTL the only thing that I'm doing is to setting 24H more to the state when read, so if an event arrives at 2020-09-10 22:00, then the TTL will update the state until 2020-09-11 22:00 and that's not what I need, I need that no matter what time the event arrives, all previous states will be updated at 2020-09-10 23:59:59

Comment: I was able to do that kind of cleaning by using a `KeyedProcessFunction` as you said, the main question was trying to find a way to do the full clean up of states into one operator at 24 hours of the day.

Comment: Updated my answer to describe a common "end of day" pattern.

Comment: I tried to edit my answer, but it was rejected. I said "If you need to remove state precisely at the end of the day, then using a broadcast stream with these types of "business logic" events would be the way to go, since that would let you iterate over **all** of the state when you get the "End of day" event in the broadcast stream.

See the [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html) about this pattern, in particular the `Context.applyToKeyedState()` method."